# Custom Exception Handler in Angular2

Tags: angular

In angular2 the exceptions are logged in the console by default. I heard that we can inherit the Angular ExceptionHandler and create our own exception handler so that we can override the default behavior. I tried to do it but didn't work. Can anyone help me on this with an example. Thanks in advance ....

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980405/module-angular2-angular2-has-no-exported-member-exceptionhandler

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of version 2.0.1, the current way of creating a custom error handler is the `ErrorHandler` interface found in `@angular/core`.

From the docs:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}
@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }]
})
class MyModule {}
```

When applying this on the root module, all children modules will receive the same error handler (unless they have another one specified in their provider list).

Comment: where i add this myErrorHandler class?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to create your own class to handle exceptions, and then bind it in your app at bootstrap time, something like this:

```
import {provide, ExceptionHandler} from '@angular/core';

class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {
    call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
       // do something with the exception
    }
 }
```

And then at bootstrap time, bind this new implementation as the  ExceptionHandler:

```
bootstrap(MyApp, 
    [provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: MyExceptionHandler})])
```

See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f14b212dc997a021d874ac0fc3e0e4d57a734fe4/modules/angular2/src/core/exception_handler.ts) for reference.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zbzllPKzAd7T0AQp22Id?p=preview)

Comment: And there is only one little problem: how are you going to get ExceptionHandler?)

Comment: I tried to add the custom exception handler but didn't work . Anyone has a working example ?

Comment: I am getting an exception when i tried with custom exception handler - 

"Cannot resolve all parameters for MyExceptionHandler(?, Boolean). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations."

Comment: Right now i believe `provide` method is deprecated. This should also work: `{provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an exception handler that works in alpha .46

```
import {ExceptionHandler} from 'angular2/angular2';

export class ERISExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {

    call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
        alert('error:' + error + ' stackTrace: ' + stackTrace + ' reason: ' + reason);
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that it will bomb trying to `super.call(error, stackTrace, reason)`. It would be great to keep the nice angular error messages going with a custom exception handler.