# Module '"angular2/angular2"' has no exported member 'ExceptionHandler'

Tags: angular

I want to customize the default exception handler behavior and to do that I want to override the ExceptionHandler class, but I get the next error when I use the next code

Error:

> ```
>   Module '"angular2/angular2"' has no exported member 'ExceptionHandler'.
> ```

Code:

```
    import {ExceptionHandler} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

Is this the correct aproach ? From where or what I have to import ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Exception Handler in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488245/custom-exception-handler-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's bug. `ExceptionHandler` must be exported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.39/modules/angular2/src/core/facade.ts#L5), but it's not.

For now for experimenting you can import `ExceptionHandler` like:

```js
import { ExceptionHandler } from 'angular2/src/core/facade/exceptions';
```

Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6s34wKjeY7VO8NgcKm3E?p=preview)

Comment: In angular2@2.0.0-beta.0 I'm using... import { ExceptionHandler } from 'angular2/src/facade/exceptions';

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new plunker (modified @alexpods version) that works in beta 11. http://plnkr.co/edit/7VEjaohuse2sLneuCIVC?p=preview

Basic differences:

- use of `provide` instead of `bind`
- other System JS paths for import