# Angular2: ngModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule are not exported members

Tags: angular

I am going through the Angular2 tutorial at
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html. All good to step Routing. Visual Studio Code shows the error at first 03 lines:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
```

as

```
[ts] 
Module '"c:/Users/ktran/Source/Repos/angular2-quickstart-ts/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'NgModule'.
```

folder node_modules:

[image]

any idea please?

Comment: Could be a misconfiguration of SystemJS?

Comment: systemjs.config.js is copied from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Then it could be a VS Code bug, as you can see in related wuestions, this with VS Code has already been asked.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980405/module-angular2-angular2-has-no-exported-member-exceptionhandler?rq=1

Comment: I have the same problem.  I also have this error on `npm start`:

app/app.module.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/exclipy/Code/ng/angular2-quickstart/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'NgModule'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some modules just get added to the new version of Angular, so if you are not updating, you can not import it.

After about half an hour of search, got a solution:

Create a new folder and cd to your folder.

In command line, Type:

```
 git clone  https://github.com/angular/quickstart
 cd quickstart
 npm install
```

And copy your old code to the newly created project

Comment: With all the regards & thanks for posting it, to me personally it somehow looks more like a workaround

Comment: ha! This was a good suggestion from Kim - it can even be more lightweight, just 1) copy from the github/angular/quickstart only the package.json dependencies and devdependencies items and 2) in your own package.json file replace those entries and then 3) do "npm install" and 4) "npm start" (it still looks like a workaround - who has the real answer?)

Comment: Thansk Kim. These classes are in 2.0.0-rc.5 while I am declaring 2.0.0-rc.4 in package.json.

Answer (score 32):

As Kim Phung stated, this is because a new RC of Angular was just released. Change the following lines in packages.json:

```
// ...snip...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",

// ...file continues...
```

Then run, in your console:

```
npm update
```

Good to go!

Comment: For someone have trouble with `npm update` make sure you run this with root/administrator on Window.

Comment: Thanks for answer ```"@angular/forms": "0.3.0",``` solved my issue

Comment: Or just run `npm i @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/router@latest` to update them all

Answer (score 12):

If this solutions didn't help you, try to **reopen VSCode**.
For me it was editor issue.

Comment: just reopening won't change anything. But I can imagine that restarting the server may. On Windows: press Ctrl-C in the console window, to close the currently running command, and resend command `ng serve`

Comment: Reopening solved the issue for me. Had the editor open during an upgrade.

Comment: This is so obvious yet so useful reminder, i too had vs code open during update and it got fixed on reopen. Thanks!

Comment: This should accepted answer :) I was wondering why it was showing me error thought it is compiling successfully!!

Answer (score 1):

if you have this type of error.
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
try this command:

> npm update

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue upgrading a sample app to 2.0.1 using the quickstart sample. 
I fixed it by updating not only the package.json, but also systemjs.config.js and typings.json

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have included the FormsModule to the ngModule imports

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule,**FormsModule** ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import this symbol in the module file. I am pretty sure that you are importing it in the component file.