# Angular 2 rc5 migration, no exported members on import

Tags: angular, typescript

I've just migrated to rc5 and I'm trying to implement the new ngModule system.
TS is returning errors for:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

Both modules have no exported member...

Comment: Could be because all angular2 packages are not up to date. Did you check the list in your package.Json file ?

Comment: How did you migrate to RC5. Changed the version in package.json? Check what version you have in your node_modules. Try `npm update`.

Comment: update the package.json to point RC5 and then try 'npm update'. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38867852/4213217

Comment: I tried both npm update and npm install. I even looked up some versions inside the dist and they're rc5. These are the @angular dependencies inside my package.json:

    `"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",`

Comment: Nevermind. Restarting visual code solved the problem. Thx!

Comment: I had a similar problem with SublimeText.  I think IDEs just need a bounce to catch up after ng node package upgrades.