# General Error handling in Angular2 - failed bindings

Tags: angular, error-handling

I recently figured out  my html content consists of

```
{{employer.userdata.firstname}}
```

while there was an implementation change to `employer.firstname` on class level. The bad side effect was that the wrong binding did not throw any kind of exception and only after some long time of debugging I figured out that `employer.userdata == undefined`

So I was thinking if there is a chance to implement some generic Exception/ErrorHandler to provide useful information on the console. I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488245/custom-exception-handler-in-angular2) with

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
export class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {
    super(true);
  }

  handleError(error) {
    console.log(`MyErrorhandler: ${error}`);
    super.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

and in my `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler }]
})
```

but still there is no console-log. Any hints how to do it *'properly'* ?

**EDIT:**

From the responses I see that my sample was too simple :-/ I rechecked my code and I have had the code like:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName"
                                formControlName="firstName"
                                [formControl]="form.controls['firstName']"
                                [(ngModel)]="employer.userdata.firstname">
```

after changing it to `employer.fistname` the whole code runs perfectly. I only got an hint after I performed a manual `doCheck()` which finally throw the Exception. I guess the Exception was thrown already before and somewhere swallowed during the init phase of the complete control ==> how to **NOT** let is swallow? My approach didn't help :-/

Comment: If employer.userdata was undefined, you would get a "Cannot read property firstname of undefined" error in the console, without doing anything special. So the problem is not that. See http://plnkr.co/edit/tEzRrVTeEUWEclKcLWhB?p=preview.

Comment: The error handler only prevents that your Angular application exits after an error. If `employmer.userdata` actually was `undefined` `{{employer.userdata.firstname}}` should show an error in your browsers console and a custom error handler can prevent showing the error in the console. If there was none, the error handler also won't receive one.

Comment: thx for the response - I've updated the example. I've tested Günters comment and see there is an error on the console - but in my use case - in my app none :-/ ==> Can this be turned off? If so -> where?

Comment: I don't think this can be turned off.

Comment: But matter of fact is that if I use `{{employer.userdata.firstname}}` it in the table as second column entry ==> the first row first element is displayed all subsequent elements are not displayed - but the table rows are framed (several 100s)! **AND** not a single error message :-/