# How to handle error if API is down in Angular2 (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)?

Tags: http, angular, ionic2, observable

My catch error method is not catching error if server is down.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(this.PATH + '/signup', details, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(res => Observable.throw(res['_body']));
```

Comment: You can handle error in the subscribe method: .subscribe(res => this.onResponse(), err => this.onError())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 HTTP - How to understand that the backend server is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601795/angular2-http-how-to-understand-that-the-backend-server-is-down)