# Angular 2 HTTP response interceptor

Tags: http, angular

In Angular 1, globally handling an HTTP response status is done with `$httpProvider`:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .service('httpResponseInterceptor', ['$q', function ($q) {
        this.response = function (response) {
            if (response.status === 418) {
                // do some stuff here
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        };
        this.responseError = function (response) {
            if (response.status === 418) {
                // do some stuff here
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        };
    }])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        // do routing, etc.

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpResponseInterceptor');
    }]);
```

In Angular 2, it is done extending `Http` something like this instead:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    Http,
    Response,
    Request,
    RequestOptions,
    RequestOptionsArgs,
    XHRBackend
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

  constructor(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(xhrBackend, requestOptions);
  }

  private catchErrors() {
    return (response: Response) => {
      if (response.status === 418) {
            // do some stuff here
      }
      return Observable.throw(response);
    };
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options)
          .catch(this.catchErrors());
  }
}
```

...and by including this in `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
    { provide: Http, useClass: HttpInterceptor }
]
```

*See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34934009/1298685) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mrgoos/45ab013c2c044691b82d250a7df71e4c) for reference.*

---

However, I am getting this error with the above Angular 2 code:

> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Http: in NgModule AppModule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This configuration worked for me; I'm using Angular 2 v2.4.1:

app.module.ts

```
{
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new HttpInterceptor(backend, options);
    },
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}
```

HttpInterceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    Http,
    ConnectionBackend,
    RequestOptions,
    RequestOptionsArgs,
    Request,
    Response,
    Headers
} from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options));
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for this! `useFactory` and `deps` is working correctly for me, instead of `useClass`.