# Handling errors globally with angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 and I want to intercept all responses and redirect user to login page if session is expired.

I came across [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934009/handling-401s-globally-with-angular), and I have been following [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37028266/2744511).

Everything compiles correctly. By inspecting in debugger I can see that `constructor` has been called, but `super.request` has never been reached.

Here is my extended `HTTP` Module

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Response, Http, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedHttpService extends Http {

  constructor(backend:XHRBackend, defaultOptions:RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url:string | Request, options?:RequestOptionsArgs):Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options).catch((error:Response) => {
      if ((error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) && (window.location.href.match(/\?/g) || []).length < 2) {
        console.log('The authentication session expires or the user is not authorised. Force refresh of the current page.');
      }
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
  }
}
```

In `app.module.ts` I have provider defined as

```
...
providers: [{
    provide: HttpModule,
    useClass: AuthenticatedHttpService
  }, SessionService, MyService]
...
```

And in `MyService` I have

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  apiUrl:string = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getData() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', 'my-token');
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiUrl + '/getData', {headers: headers}
      ).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me in a right direction what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further inspection I have found a solution for my specific problem.

First I had to apply changes to `app.module.ts` regarding Http Provider like this

```
{
  provide: AuthenticatedHttpService,
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
      return new AuthenticatedHttpService(backend, options);
    },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
},
```

Then in `MyService` I am using `AuthenticatedHttpService` instead `Http` like this.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {AuthenticatedHttpService} from '../../_services/authenticated-http.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  apiUrl:string = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http:AuthenticatedHttpService) {
  }

  getData() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', 'my-token');
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiUrl + '/getData', {headers: headers}
      ).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

After I have applied these changes everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a base service
2. Inherit all your services from this base service
3. Write all your global code inside this base service

This would be the best solution