# Response Interceptor in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-http

I send many HTTP requests into a server, and the server returns each of them a response with a new access token (maybe in header or body).

Is there any way to handle all responses before or after it finishes, like middleware for a request in some back-end framework?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Angular version 4+ you can look at `HttpClientModule` which provides support for interceptors.

**eg**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(event => {}, err => {
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            console.log("Error Caught By Interceptor");
            //Observable.throw(err);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Register to app.module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: 
              AngularInterceptor, multi: true } ]
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

More on [HttpClientModule](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

If you are not using angular v4 check this answer on SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37028266/2708210)

Answer (score -1):

you can use **http-interceptor** Package

The package source[ng-http-interceptor](https://github.com/gund/ng-http-interceptor)

its handle every request and response of http