# Angular4 redirect to static error page when backend serer is down

Tags: angular

I have a Angular4 application and when the backend server goes down i want it to redirect to a error page. Im using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934009/handling-401s-globally-with-angular/37028266#37028266) solution to check wheter the server is down. But how can i route to a static error page from here? I cant use router here becaus then ill get cyclic dependency error.

Comment: Can you show how you are using `router` when cyclic dependency error is triggered?

Comment: as the link you references advises: use the HttpInterceptor. Then you can use the router to redirect

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra If i do that then there wil be few request that it will not cover. I hae few requests that are made using Http instead of HttpClient, and it seems Http and Router cannot be refrenced from same class. How can i use router from a class that imports or exctends Http ?

Comment: @AsimHashmi i just have router inside the constructor parameter list. Thats it.

Comment: If it's just redirect you can always use simple `window.location.href` or `window.location.open(...)`

Comment: @MarcinTomczyk yes that worked. I just have to place my error page as static content. Only issue i have is the url: assets/errorPage/errorPage.html. Is there a way to make this more nice ?

Comment: @MarkoTaht Yes, look into `angular.json` and use build assets options. You can copy files by name or use object with glob, input and output options to change how static assets are emmited